# Content search query WP multiple sites

Tags: 2013, search

I am using the below query to show a particular CT from a sub site of this site.  In the same space I want to show results from another site in the collection.  Is this possible?

```
path:{Site.URL}
ContentTypeId:0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D000F6AAE38AC4E3D41A4AFABC6180DF3B50600B6F7B9BED946174E8C4D468BDD121AAA* owstaxIdCountry:{User.Country}  AND PublishingDateSortable<{Today+1}
```

Some extra info I should have included.  Here is a diagram of the site.  The query is on site 1, with the content on sub 1 and sub 2.  The query will be the same but only content type ID will change.[image: Site Layout]

Comment: That should be possible. Can you specify what exactly you want to show in addition to this query? It would be easiest, if you could provide both the first query and the second query that you want to "merge" the results from, then we can work out the full query that encompasses both results.

Answer (score 0):

Although it looks like a small question, but the answer is unfortunately  negative.

You mentioned "The query will be the same but only content type ID will change." So I assume you want to drop another CSWP in site 1, and show the result with a different local content type from site 2.

I did a quick search test with the same structure you provided, in conclusion: 
(1) Parent site couldn't find both CT1 and CT2.
(2) Site 1 couldn't find CT2.
(3) Site 2 couldn't find CT1.

Suggested solution: you can either create content types in parent site, use cross-site publishing, or content type hub.

P.S. My local search is crawling very slow, I would update again if there's anything changed.